# What clamp to use to transition from 1950s-era fabric-jacket NM?

Tags: conduit, junction-box, transition

Our doorbell transformer is powered via an original 1950s-era fabric jacketed 2-conductor NM (internal conductors are plastic-jacketed). Photo below shows that NM leaving electrical box; doorbell transformer is sitting out in the open on a wooden shelf on the other side of the visible wood enclosure.

As part of replacing the doorbell transformer to power a Ring doorbell, I'd like to mount the new transformer to a proper metal junction box, which will be secured to a stud in the unfinished garage wall. There is about 3-4 feet of this old but in good condition NM running in the wall to the transformer. I can think of two main choices for connecting the old NM:

1. Just run it to the new metal junction box and use some sort of box-entry clamp to secure it at a knockout hole. Would I use a modern clamp designed for NM-B, or some special clamp?
2. Protect it for that short run by running it into something like a liquidtite or flex conduit section (maybe 3/4" trade size?) for the run to the junction box. How would I secure it at the transition to conduit? And would I remove the outer fabric jacket and just run the internal plastic insulated conductors in the conduit to the junction box?

[image]

diagram of transformer, side view with 120V connections up:
[image: diagram of transformer, side view with 120V connections up]

Comment: Aren't doorbell transformers usually "in the open" like that? Maybe for heat dissipation or such?

Comment: @gnicko Yes. There's 120V wires going in one side of the transformer, into a circular opening that threads into a standard  j box knockout opening with locknut. The metal transformer body and lower voltage output terminals are exposed. I want to run the old NM into the other side of the j box and connect their conductors with the transformer's 120V input wires inside the j box. Metal box in photo is circuit breaker box supplying the NM.

Comment: How accessible is the existing run? I don't like keeping the old NM unless it's a real headache to run new stuff.

Comment: @KMJ It's accessible, but I don't yet want to open the electrical panel (remove dead front). As you can see from photo, there are other old NM cables squished in and I don't want to disturb them at this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Just run it to the new metal junction box and use some sort of box-entry clamp to secure it at a knockout hole. Would I use a modern clamp designed for NM-B, or some special clamp?

Yes, use a metal box and a [standard clamp](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-3-8-in-Non-Metallic-NM-Twin-Screw-Cable-Clamp-Connectors-5-Pack-20511/100133208). Just make sure it is the right size for your box knockout.

[image: clamp]